# Default values for string format use in string (template)

Tags: python, string-formatting

hope you can help me with the below problem that i have in python.
I am trying to use string format of a template but need some how to have default values.

```
template = """
Server {isServerRunning}
NTP {isNTPrunning}
Application {isAppRunning}
"""

test = template.format(isServerRunning='is not running')

print test

OUTPUT:
Server is not running
NTP is running
Application is running
```

(lets say default values for those 3 paramters should be 'is running')

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Can you encase that in a function like:

```
def test(isServerRunning='is running',
         isNTPrunning='is running',
         isAppRunning='is running'): 
         return template.format(
             isServerRunning=isServerRunning, 
             isNTPrunning=isNTPrunning, 
             isAppRunning=isAppRunning)
```